# How can I show a simple notification on Windows using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, windows, notifications

How can I show notifications on Windows from a Ruby script?

Currently, I'm using GMail messages but there's a delay...
I'm trying to receive an alert and seconds/nanoseconds matter.

Thank you

Comment: What operating system? Where is the alert sent from? Where is it going?

Comment: windows 10,  I'm using Net::HTTP.get requests to another server and sending alerts to myself.  I know how to print but I have a lot windows open...I need an actual "alert"

Comment: How about just opening a message box that you have to click OK on? Would something like that be good enough?

Comment: Also let me confirm: you want the alert to be shown on your W10 screen?

Comment: YES, that's what I want.  I tried this gem called messagebox with MessageBox.new("#{response.code}").show   and obviously that didn't work.  Thanks for being patient with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to show a notification on Windows with Ruby is to use  `Win32API` and just call [`MessageBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox):

```
require 'win32api'

MessageBox = Win32API.new('user32', 'MessageBox', ['L', 'P', 'P', 'L'], 'I')
MessageBox.call(0, "Something important happened", "Alert", 0)
```

Another more advanced setup is to use something like the [Growl notifier](http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/default.aspx), and couple it with the [`ruby_gntp`](http://snaka.info/ruby_gntp/) gem, or [Notifu](http://www.paralint.com/projects/notifu/) + [`rb_notifu`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rb-notifu/). See here for more info on these types of notification systems:

https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/System-notifications

Comment: Thank you, when I tried win32api I could get it to just say "alert" but not the json string... Hopefully one of these works.  I'm going to look into growl, notifu etc

Comment: growl works and i set it up in like....5 minutes, even with the json.  THANK YOU.  I don't think i'm going to try notifu.  Maybe as a backup.